# "Enter Passcode for Other iPhone"

Tags: iphone, ios, password

I'm setting up an iPhone for a friend, who lost her old iPhone. She got a new iPhone at the Apple store. But when they configured it, she neglected to write down the new passcode & then keep it where she could find it again.

Fast forward to today. Now I'm trying to turn on "Find My" & iCloud backup, but can't because it requires that passcode. After checking with her, I followed instructions to reset the phone ("restore"). And now I'm going through the setup procedure: I chose "English", then "United States", then entered a new passcode (WHICH I WROTE DOWN!).

But now it says, "Enter Passcode for Other iPhone". That appears to refer to her old iPhone, which as I mentioned was lost, and I don't think she knew the passcode for that one either.

I thought I was out of the woods when I was able to set a new passcode, but suddenly there's this new hurdle to overcome. TIA for any ideas on how to get past this!

Comment: Fixed! Worked with Apple support. Not sure what the initial problem was (1st tech "elevated" the call to the next level up), but after a software update & logging in again, it now seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip by this. Click the option that says you've forgotten that password.

It will ask to reset certain information - this includes your Keychain (passwords saved in Safari most commonly) and some other information. Accept this and continue.

Comment: Thank you! If it happens again I will try this.